# Play-Rest API with Java - basic response

Tags: java, rest, playframework, restangular

I'm new in the server-side , and I'm trying to learn how to use play in rest api with java and restangular. I made a project for java in the intellij. I want the GET request to return an html page and not html.scala page.
how do I change this function that it will return the app/views/index.html instead the app/views/index.html.scala

also if someone have a good website to learn from, it will help a lot

the function in java :

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

}
```

the routes page :

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Comment: why don't you want the index.html.scala?

Comment: cause i dont want to use scala in my project

Comment: ok - well that doesn't mean it's only for scala devs.  See docs https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTemplates#A-type-safe-template-engine-based-on-Scala and  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11126678/1956540 and

Comment: Scala in this case is for the templates. It's not for your business logic, all your normal code, controllers, services and stuff. It's just very easy to understand HTML + scala-based helper methods. It's similar to JSP if you come from the Java EE world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question with good answer with a lot of examples. 
you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971464/play-framework-how-to-route-to-a-html-page-in-the-public-folder).
The easiest way is to make a GET request for the / and to send the destination also, like this:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public",file="index.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

Play use [twirl](https://github.com/playframework/twirl) as a template engine. I am not sure if you can easely change it to some other template engine but I think you can. Any way, as I see you are looking for a way just output simple HTML file. You can do this with default Assets controller:

this string in your route

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

would handle any files in the public. So if you will add to the *public* directory the simple */html/hello.html* file then Play will render it by the url */assets/html/hello.html*. You can change URL as you like in the rote file